# "Converting" from int[] to std::array at fread?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I was wondering and have not found any advice, on how to convert a C-style integer array to a new std::array from C++11

I love the std::array and use it a lot, anyhow if I read in data from binary files, I work around to copy the values. 
Isn't there a simpler way when using fread?

```
FILE* fp; // initalize not important here
int arr[12];
std::array<int,12> stdarr;
fread(arr, sizeof(int), 12, fp);
for(int i=0; i < 12; i++)
stdarr[i] = arr[i];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading into the <strike>address of the first element</strike> array's underlying data block should work:

```
fread(stdarr.data(), sizeof(int), stdarr.size(), fp);
```

Comment: [`stdarr.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) would be slightly more idiomatic.